# complex css image centering help?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, alignment

My problem is a bit more complex than the title says. Sorry, I don't know how to be more specific...

I'm working on a website and I came across a part where I should display some thumbnails. The thing is, the thumbnails are not matching in dimensions. (I know, it sounds ridiculous, since this is thumbnails are for, right?) No, there is simply NO WAY to create them in the same dimensions!! I've managed to create a HTML+CSS structure to fix this problem, and the images are not stretching to fit their containers if they are smaller while keeping their aspect ratio.

The only issue remaining, is to center the images. Since setting margin to "0 auto" or "auto 0" are not helping, I've tried setting up [multiple containers and setting the margins](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) to position the images. This is also not working: if I put a 120x120 picture in a 120x80 inner container, and I set the container's top and left margin to -50%, the margins become -60px both. Can this be fixed? Or is there yet another way to center images?

I'm open to any suggestions!

HTML:

```
<div id="roll">
<div class="imgfix">
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            @if (ImageDimensionHelper.WhereToAlignImg(item.Width, item.Height, 120, 82) == ImgAlign.Width)

            <!-- ImageDimensionHelper tells me if the image should fit the 
            container with its width or height. I set the class of the img
            accordingly. -->

            {
            <img class="width" src="@Url.Content(item.URL)" alt="@item.Name"/>
            }
            else 
            {
            <img class="height" src="@Url.Content(item.URL)" alt="@item.Name"/>
            }    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imgfix{ overflow:hidden; }
.imgfix .outer { width:100%; height:100%;}
.imgfix .inner { width:100%; height:100%; margin-top:-50%; margin-left:-50%; }
/*This div (.inner) gets -60px for both margins every time, regardless of the size of itself, or the image inside it*/
#roll .imgfix { width:120px; height:82px; border: 1px #5b91ba solid; } 
#roll .imgfix .outer { margin-top:41px; margin-left:60px; }
/*since I know specificly what these margins should be, I set them explicitly, because 50% got the wrong size.*/
#roll .imgfix img.width { width:120px; height:auto; margin: auto 0; }
#roll .imgfix img.height { height:82px; width:auto; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Comment: do you want to do a pure css centering or are you not against using js to do it ? I can provide you a solution with jQuery (maybe dimension plugin extension)

Comment: I'd like to stick to css-only as long it is possible.

Comment: Maybe I will have to use js for this, and the fallback would be to show the images in the top left corner.

Comment: I've improved my answer with a hopefully working demo which only uses CSS to position the images but it does rely on knowing the image dimensions at the point which the `<img>` elements are generated in order to add an inline CSS `margin` rule. From your question it looks like you have those dimensions, so I hope they can be used in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>If I understand correctly [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ThHBM/) should do what you want. However, it will not work in all browsers. So if you need to support IE6/7, then this is not the correct solution.</strike>

**Edit:**

> My problem is a bit more complex than the title says

That is an understatement!

I **think** I have [**something working**](http://jsfiddle.net/ThHBM/4/), although you will need to add some inline style depending on the size of the image. Most of the CSS is shared, so it is only the `margin-left` and `margin-top` that needs setting depending on if the image you want to centre is larger or smaller than one or both of the thumbnail dimensions (in this example `120x80px`).

I see from your question that you know the image dimensions in the server side code, so you should be able to generalise the logic to create the necessary inline style for each image. In summary I am using one of 2 general styles for any given `img`

```
img.stretchHorizontal { /* use when img width < 120px */
    width:100%;
}
img.stretchVertical { /* use when img height < 80px */
    height:100%;
}
```

Remaining CSS for completeness:

```
.outer {
    width:120px;
    height:80px;
    border:1px #5b91ba solid;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block; /* not necessary, but nice for demo */
}
.inner {
    width:120px;
    height:80px;
}
#roll {
    margin:100px 0 0 100px; /* just to move everything down and left a bit */
}
```

Then depending on if the image needs `.stretchHorizontal` or `.stretchVertical`, add a calculated `margin-top`, `margin-left` or both `margin-top` and `margin-left`. The general rules seem to be:

- If stretchVertical add `margin-left:(scaled img width/-2)+(inner width/2)`
- If stretchHorizontal add `margin-top:((scaled img height)/-2)+(inner height /2)`
- If no stretch required (img is larger than 120x80) add `margin-top:img height - 80/-2` and `margin-left:(img width/-2)+(inner width/2)`

The [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ThHBM/4/) uses a few different image sizes as examples.

```
<div id="roll">
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner" style="margin:-20px 0 0 0">
            <!-- margin-top:((scaled img height)/-2)+(inner height /2) = ((120/100 * 100 = 120)/-2)+ 40 = -20px -->
            <img class="stretchHorizontal" src="viewport/yoda.jpg" alt=""/> <!-- 100x100 -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner" style="margin:0 0 0 -100px">
            <!-- margin-left:(scaled img width/-2)+(inner width/2) so margin-left:((80/80 * 320 /-2)+60 = -160+60 = -100px-->
            <img class="stretchVertical" src="viewport/galaxies.png" alt=""/> <!-- 320x80 -->
        </div>
    </div><br/>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner" style="margin:-20px 0 0 0">
            <!-- margin-top:((scaled img height)/-2)+(inner height /2) = ((120/120 * 120 = 120)/-2)+ 40 = -60 + 40 = -20px margin-left:(120/-2)+60 = 0-->
            <img src="viewport/luke.jpg" alt=""/> <!-- 120x120 -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner" style="margin:-160px 0 0 -190px">
            <!--  margin-top:img height - 80/-2 = -160px margin-left:(img width/-2)+(inner width/2) so margin-left:(500/-2)+60 = -190px-->
            <img src="viewport/cookie_cutter.jpg" alt=""/> <!-- 500x400 -->
        </div>
    </div><br/>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner" style="margin:-20px 0 0 0">
            <!-- margin-top:((scaled img height)/-2)+(inner height /2) = ((120/50 * 50 = 120)/-2)+ 40 = -20px -->
            <img class="stretchHorizontal" src="viewport/vadar.gif" alt=""/> <!-- 50x50 stretchVertical or stretchHorizontal does not matter for images smaller than both inner dimensions -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner" style="margin:-50px 0 0 -65px">
            <!-- margin-top:img height - 80/-2 = -50px margin-left:(250/-2)+60=-65px -->
            <img src="viewport/starwars.jpg" alt=""/> <!-- 250x180 -->
        </div>
    </div><br/>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner" style="margin:-50px 0 0 -30px">
            <!-- margin-top:img height - 80/-2 = -50px margin-left:(180/-2)+60=-30px-->
            <img src="viewport/big_luke.jpg" alt=""/> <!-- 180x180 -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner" style="margin:-200px 0 0 0">
            <!-- margin-top:scaled img height/-2+(inner height /2) so (120/50 * 200 = 480)/-2 = -240px + 40 = -200px-->
            <img class="stretchHorizontal" src="viewport/bookmark.jpg" alt=""/> <!-- 50x200 -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I doubt this is completely bug free, but I hope it's a good start for your problem :-)

Comment: Almost. I want to stretch the images so there wouldn't be any blank space around them. I solved the stretching, but it seem like the centering tricks are not working with negative margins.

Comment: If you want to stretch the images you could just change the CSS to `img { width:120px; height:82px; }`. From the question, I thought you wanted to center the images. Is this not correct? **Edit:** OK I understand the question now. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Yes, I've come to a similar conclusion. Unfortunately my colleague who I work with on this is 'allergic' to inline styles and javascript. But it seems like this cannot work without one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Images are inline. set them to display:block to use margin:auto or just use text-align:center within the div.inner element.

For vertical alignment you need to to set display:table-cell to the div.inner element and additionally vertical-align:middle

Comment: It didn't help. Nothing's changed.

Comment: do you tried to use text-align or set the display of the images to block

Comment: Both actually. The problem is they should be centered both vertically and horizontally. Text-align only solves the horizontal part, and the margin: auto seems to do nothing.

Comment: for vertical alignment you need to to set display:table-cell to the div.inner element and additionally vertical-align:middle